Why do React Server Components need to have "use client" when compound components are used?
Take a simple card component, in NextJS v14:
// card.tsx
"use client";

import React, { useState, ReactNode } from "react";

// Parent component
export function Card({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid #ccc", padding: "16px", borderRadius: "8px" }}>
      <button onClick={() => setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)} style={{ marginBottom: "8px" }}>
        {isExpanded ? "Collapse" : "Expand"}
      </button>
      {isExpanded && children}
    </div>
  );
}

// Header component
function CardHeader({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  return <div style={{ fontWeight: "bold", marginBottom: "8px" }}>{children}</div>;
}

Card.Header = CardHeader;

It uses use client because of the useState and exports a compound component.
In a server component, the card is used:
// cards.tsx
import { Card, } from './card';

export const Cards = () => {
  return (
    <Card>
      <Card.Header>Server-Rendered Header</Card.Header>
    </Card>
  );
};


This throws an error:

Error: Unsupported Server Component type: undefined

The only fix I could find was to make cards.tsx a client component ('use client').
Is there any way of getting a compound component to import correctly so the parent doesn't have to become a client component as well?

Please recreate your error here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/next14-v9zkqpga?file=app%2Fcard.tsx,app%2Fpage.tsx,app%2Flayout.tsx and link it. I see a different error

@TusharShahi - Looks like the common fix is to make everything run on the client, or re-import the compound components. The error you have is similar, not sure why mine is giving a different error, but the outcome is the same ... https://medium.com/@fdikmen/fixing-could-not-find-the-module-error-in-nextjs-with-ant-design-3ae2cfe0160d

Yes, Here is the GH link

Thanks - "Instead what you should do is export each thing separately." is the appropriate comment :+1:

As per the GitHub comment on NextJS repo - GitHub Issue 44030

This behavior is intentional. 'use client' creates a boundary in the module graph. When you import from a client module into a server module, what you're actually importing is a special, opaque client reference that the RSC runtime knows how to send down to the browser. You can't actually access the export itself — it's only useful for passing to the client.
To make this work, we rely on the client exports being statically known at build time, using JavaScript export syntax.
Keep in mind that assigning to an export alone actually works fine. It's probably not a great idea for other reasons, because module side effects complicate your bundle graph and make it harder to perform optimizations like tree shaking. The error only happens when you attempt to access it on the server. (If you import the same thing into a client module, and access it there, it works fine.)
Instead what you should do is export each thing separately.

NextJS server components work as expected
